How to store a string array in a zero_copy struct
this is my struct
and i want to use whitelist_uuid field to store a string-type UUID.
pub const WHITE_PUBKEY_SIZE_USIZE: usize = 128;
#[account(zero_copy)]
pub struct ProtocolConfig {
    pub protocol_fee_rate: u32,
    pub whitelist_protocol_fee_rate: u32,
    pub whitelist_uuid: [String; WHITE_PUBKEY_SIZE_USIZE],
    pub future_use: [u8; 128], //for future use
}

and the error


The best answer is: "don't". You must know the size at compile-time to be zero-copy, you can't do that for String (generally).
What most people do is stored a fixed-length u8 slice, leaving the unused space as zeros. You can convert to/form something like UTF-8 or whatever byte representation you like as needed. For example, Pyth stores the feed ID as: pub type FeedId = [u8; 32];
Use a u8 slice that is as long as the longest String you plan to store, and make an array of those like
pub strings: [[u8; MAX_LEN]; WHITE_PUBKEY_SIZE_USIZE],

If your String is really a uuid and your uuid is fixed-length like most are, then it's even easier, since the fixed length is perfect for your application.

Okay, thank you for your reply. I think this method is excellent. Regarding zero_copy, I still have a question: I just tested changing WHITE_PUBKEY_SIZE_USIZE to 256/512, but the size of my .so file did not change. Why is that? If I change WHITE_PUBKEY_SIZE_USIZE to 512, will calling this instruction consume more CU?If it consumes more, will the increase be significant?

It's not going to make much of a difference in CU, maybe a few dozen CU (out of a budget of 200,000). You will pay slightly more in rent (256 bytes is 0.00267264 SOL), and that's about it.
